# Is it possible to use Rails 3 without bundler?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bundler

We are deploying our apps as RPM linux packages (with all the dependencies also packaged in RPMs). It turns out that bundler is problematic in this situation and it only complicates our build process - we would like to get rid of it.

Is it possible to run Rails 3 app without it forcing Ruby to use system rubygems? How?

Answer (score 2):

In the book **Rails 3 Way** there is a statement describing that the easiest way to remove Bundler is to delete Gemfile* files. That's it. It just works.

Answer (score 0):

You could install all gems manually using `gem install gemname`. In your situation or if you do not have sudo rights it is perhaps recommendable to install the gem files locally in your user directory using

```
gem install --user-install gemname
```

You can also install your gems locally with bundler:

```
bundle install --path ~/.gem
```

Comment: Hey, I think you misunderstood me. I already have all the rubygems installed system-wide (from RPMs). I just dont want to start Rails 3 using Bundler. Can Rails 3 live without it? How to remove it completely.

Comment: I am sorry, but this is completely irrelevant to my problem. Others tend to thing its the solution, while it is not.